# Could not find column 'PredictedLabel'

Tags: c#, ml.net

I'm using ML.Net and trying to cluster some data, and the exception I'm getting is in the title: 'Could not find  column 'PredictedLabel'. But I do have this column in my prediction class!

```
    public class ClusterPrediction
    {
        public uint Label { get; set; }
        // Predicted label from the trainer.
        //[ColumnName("PredictedLabel")] <-- doesn't make a differnce if I have this or not
        public uint PredictedLabel { get; set; }
        public float[] Score { get; set; } = new float[0];
        public float[] Features { get; set; } = new float[0];
    }
```

Here is how I setup my pipeline:

```
            var clusterSchema = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(InputCombinedClusterData));
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var col = clusterSchema[i];
                var itemType = ((VectorDataViewType)col.ColumnType).ItemType;
                col.ColumnType = new VectorDataViewType(itemType, InputCombinedClusterData.LOOKBACK);
            }

            var trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(data.TrainingData);
            var options = new KMeansTrainer.Options
            {
                // will tune this later 
                NumberOfClusters = 15,
                OptimizationTolerance = 1e-9f,
                MaximumNumberOfIterations = 10000,
            };

            var fundamentalCols = new List<string> { tons of columns };

            string featuresColumnName = "Features";
            var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("Sector")
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("Industry"));

            foreach (var col in fundamentalCols)
            {
                pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax(col));
            }
            
            pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate(featuresColumnName, "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Sector", "Industry", {lots more columns}));
            pipeline.Append(mlContext.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans(options));

            // Train the model.
            var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);

            // test the model
            var testData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(data.TestingData);

            // Run the model on test data set
            var transformedTestData = model.Transform(testData);

            // Goes BOOM here
            var predictions = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<ClusterPrediction>(
                transformedTestData, reuseRowObject: false).ToList();
```

I do have an alternate clustering trainer that DOES work, but it has far fewer columns. I'm not seeing the difference why the one above with more columns would blow up on not finding a PredictedLabel column when both trainers are using the same prediction class? Here is the one that does work for reference:

```
            var clusterSchema = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(InputPriceClusterData));
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var col = clusterSchema[i];
                var itemType = ((VectorDataViewType)col.ColumnType).ItemType;
                col.ColumnType = new VectorDataViewType(itemType, InputPriceClusterData.LOOKBACK);
            }

            var trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(data.TrainingData);
            var options = new KMeansTrainer.Options
            {
                NumberOfClusters = 15,
                OptimizationTolerance = 1e-9f,
                MaximumNumberOfIterations = 10000
            };

            // Define the trainer.
            string featuresColumnName = "Features";
            var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms
                .Concatenate(featuresColumnName, "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume")
                .Append(mlContext.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans(options));

            // Train the model.
            var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);

            // test the model
            var testData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(data.TestingData);

            // Run the model on test data set.
            var transformedTestData = model.Transform(testData);

            // Convert IDataView object to a list.
            var predictions = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<ClusterPrediction>(
                transformedTestData, reuseRowObject: false).ToList();
```

For the initial broken trainer, what am I missing? Ordering of the appends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a bit of a facepalm moment, but the `.Append` method on a pipeline doesn't do an in place append like `someIList.Sort()` would. I also found that I can batch up all the column pairs for normalization too. Doing it all in 1 shot resolved the issue:

```
            string featuresColumnName = "Features";
            var colPairs = new List<InputOutputColumnPair>();
            foreach (var col in fundamentalCols)
            {
                colPairs.Add(new InputOutputColumnPair(col, col));
            }

            var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("Sector")
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("Industry"))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax(colPairs.ToArray()))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate(featuresColumnName, "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Sector", "Industry", {boatload of columns}))
                .Append(mlContext.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans(options));
```